# Why is the size of array in TCL script is not given properly by array size <array_name>

Tags: tcl

Here I am having a array of 4 elements but the it prints the value as 11 so how does the size has become 11 instead of 4

```
array set ipname {UART TEST SPI I2C}
set bsize [array size ipname];
puts "$bsize"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `array set` (which only makes *two* elements in your case!) does not remove any existing contents of the array, which must have had between 9 and 11 elements in it previously. If I run your code in a bare `tclsh`, it prints `2`. If I then follow up with `parray`, it tells me what it did:

```
% parray ipname
ipname(SPI)  = I2C
ipname(UART) = TEST
```

Comment: Once we have 4 elements in a array it will give correct size only if its size increased ?? i.e if the elements are reduces it always gives 4 and if more than 4 it provides accurate result ?

Comment: Try: `set bsize [llength [array names ipname]]`